# Trait 'Stripe/ApiOperations/Request' not found

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm getting this error when I manually install Stripe PHP library

> Fatal error: Trait 'Stripe\ApiOperations\Request' not found in /home/sites/website.com/public_html/testing/includes/stripe-php/lib/ApiResource.php on line 10

My website config file contains reference to Api keys, loads the class and sets the directory

```
// Stripe API keys
    $st_test_secret_key = "sk_test_....";
    $st_test_public_key = "pk_test_...";

    // File path to the Strip library
    $path_to_stripe_lib = dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/stripe-php/lib/';

    // include_once($path_to_stripe_lib . 'init.php');
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/includes/stripe-php/init.php');

    use Stripe\Stripe;
    use Stripe\Charge;

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe[$st_test_secret_key]);
```

Within the init file I have reloaded the namespace in an effort to ensure it's true

```
    use Stripe\Stripe;
    use Stripe\Charge;

    // Stripe singleton
    require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/Stripe.php');

    // Utilities
    require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/Util/RequestOptions.php');
    require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/Util/Set.php');
    require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib/Util/Util.php');
```

And then the ApiResource file looks like this

```
<?php

    namespace Stripe;

    /**
      * Class ApiResource.
    */
    abstract class ApiResource extends StripeObject
    {
     use ApiOperations\Request;

     /**
     * @return \Stripe\Util\Set A list of fields that can be their own type of
 * API resource (say a nested card under an account for example), and if
 * that resource is set, it should be transmitted to the API on a create or
 * update. Doing so is not the default behavior because API resources
 * should normally be persisted on their own RESTful endpoints.
 */
public static function getSavedNestedResources()
{
    static $savedNestedResources = null;
    if (null === $savedNestedResources) {
        $savedNestedResources = new Util\Set();
    }

    return $savedNestedResources;
}
```

etc

I have checked multiple other answers and seem to indicate that the /stripe reference is messed up somewhere but I cannot find the right solution

Comment: Unsure what the exact problem is, but the line `$path_to_stripe_lib = dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/stripe-php/lib/';` shouldn't have the added `lib` at the end there. That is if you intend to do something like `require_once($path_to_stripe_lib . '/init.php');`

Comment: Thank you that helped and now I have a new error I can work! 

I didnt realise the /lib/ structure was built into the init file